# Entity Framework responding very late at first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My WebAPI code is hosted on a GoDaddy server.

**I have 2 issues:**

> 1. The action method returns a response after 35 seconds for the first call after the code is updated on the server. From this issue, I am
>      assuming that the application pool recycles and then it takes time,
>      but I'm not sure.
> 2. The same amount of time is being taken when a user sends a request to the server the second day. I am not sure why each request takes a
>      lot of time. The application pool is not recycled in this case.

**Class library project name: BusinessEntites**

```
public class BE_User
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Class library project name: IDAL**

```
public interface IAccount
{
    Task<KeyValuePair<String, BE_User>> GetUserLoginDetails(BE_User userDetails);
}
```

**Class library project name: DatabaseDesign**

```
internal class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BE_User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.UserID);
        Property(x => x.UserName).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        ToTable("tblUser");
    }
}
```

**Class library project name: DatabaseDesign**

```
public class ModelGeneration : DbContext
{
    public ModelGeneration()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateDatabase"] ==
           Convert.ToInt16(UpdateDatabase.Yes).ToString())
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<
                    ModelGeneration, DatabaseDesign.Migrations.Configuration>());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType
               && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
                    typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
    public virtual IDbSet<BE_User> tblUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Class library project name: DatabaseDesign**

```
internal sealed class Configuration 
              : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseDesign.ModelGeneration>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateDatabase"] == 
                        Convert.ToInt16(UpdateDatabase.Yes).ToString())
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void User(DatabaseDesign.ModelGeneration context)
    {
        BE_User SuperAdminUser = new BE_User
        {
            UserName = "Administrator",
            Password = "Some encrypted Password",
        };
        context.tblUser.Add(SuperAdminUser);
    }

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseDesign.ModelGeneration context)
    {
        User(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Class library project name: DAL**

```
public class Dal_Account : IAccount
{
    public async Task<KeyValuePair<String, BE_User>> GetUserLoginDetails(
                                                                     BE_User userDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var userContext = new ModelGeneration())
            {
                userContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var data = await userContext.tblUser
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.UserName == userDetails.UserName && 
                                i.Password == userDetails.Password);
                if (data == null)
                    return new KeyValuePair<string, BE_User>("User not found", null);
                return new KeyValuePair<String, BE_User>("", data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<String, BE_User>(ex.Message, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**WebAPI Project**

```
[Route("api/v1/GetUserLoginDetails"), HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserLoginDetails(BE_User userDetails)
{
    var result = await _account.GetUserLoginDetails(userDetails);
    return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result.Key, result = result.Value });
}
```

Do I need any code improvements or do any settings need to be modified?

Comment: 1) by default the app pool is shut down after a certain amount of inactivity. I think the default is 15 minutes. There is a configuration setting for this. 2) There is some time required to compile an EF query for the first time, and also to create an execution plan for sql query. In addition on the first request sql cache will be cold, which adds impact on the execution time. -- If I had this problem I'd try to come up with a way to keep these always hot, like a service elsewhere that issues a request once in a while to keep things hot.

Comment: May I ask, How can I modify the Timeout setting for app Pool in Godaddy ?

Comment: No idea. Probably write to GoDaddy support and ask them?

Comment: @zespri: I had a call with GoDaddy Customer Care. They said they will not support any change in IIS Pool Settings. As the settings are fixed. Please find the screenshot for the settings here. http://prntscr.com/8vpkzf

Comment: Here you go. Find another provider if you want to change these.

Comment: how big is your database (no. of tables) ? and how many contexts do you have ? there is a bit of late for the context with thousands of tables when it it constructs itself in memory with the first hit, but I am not sure if 35 seconds is reasonable ?